# Run method when SlidingMenu opens or closes

Tags: android, slidingmenu

I am using Jeremy Feinstein's sliding menu for Android, and I need help running a method when the SlidingMenu opens and/or closes. I'd like to change an icon depending on the state of the menu. I tried subclassing SlidingMenu and overwriting the toggle method, like so:

```
public class SlidingMenuCustom extends SlidingMenu {

ImageView plus;

public SlidingMenuCustom(Activity activity, ImageView plus) {
    super(activity);
    this.plus = plus;
}

@Override
public void toggle(){
    super.toggle();
    Log.d("Hello", Global.debug + " " + isMenuShowing());
    if(isMenuShowing()){
        plus.setImageResource(R.drawable.sidenavminus);
    }else{
        plus.setImageResource(R.drawable.sidenavplus);
    }


}

}
```

But then I realized that toggle is only ever called if I call it, so that wouldn't work. Is there something else that I can do to run a method when the sliding menu opens or closes?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> jfeinstein10 sliding menu provide listnere when sliding menu open and
>   close

```
Override below method to your class
```

1.Open sliding menu listener

```
     slidingmenu.setOnOpenedListener(new OnOpenedListener() {

        @Override
        public void onOpened() {
               //execute your code
        }

    });
```

1.Close sliding menu listener

```
     slidingmenu.setOnClosedListener(new OnOpenedListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClosed() {
               //execute your code
         }

    });
```

Comment: But how to differentiate between primary and secondary menu?